# Unstring a string: is it Possible?

Tags: c#, string, save, settings, design-patterns

I'm currently having the Problem of trying to save certain properties into the Settings.settings as a string.

if I use the following in my class:

```
string Pattern0 = SafeFileName(currMail.SenderName);
```

everything is fine, but once i try to save it in the Settings as a string, it turns everything into a strings and I can't use it as Properties anymore,
Is there a way to Unstring a String?

Or is there another Type (other than: string) i could use that would give me the desired result?

[image]

and here is what it Looks like in the Settings.Designer

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("SafeFileName(currMail.SenderName)")]
    public string NamePattern0 {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["NamePattern0"]));
        }
        set {
            this["NamenPattern0"] = value;
        }
    }
```

As you can see it gets turned into a String, but i Need it as an Object or something

Comment: Can you show us some more code? What does _it turn to strings_?

Answer (score 0):

[DefaultSettingValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.defaultsettingvalueattribute.aspx) requires that the default value can be represented as a string. Typically you use this string to specify the default value.